Problem with Spring Boot,mysql and Docker
I have a spring boot application that has a connection to the mysql database, when I try to dockerize it and create the image whenever the application image will run these logs
2024-07-24 17:45:44 2024-07-24T17:45:44.621-03:00 ERROR 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenFilter' defined in URL [jar:nested:/app.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/br/com/kotlinspring/KotlinSpring/security/jwt/JwtTokenFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService': Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in URL 

logs: https://pastecord.com/ixusejafup
but I believe it is a connection problem with mysql
this is my docker compose
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gameplay
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3308
    ports:
      - 3308:3308
    expose:
      - 3308
    networks:
      - erudio-network
  gameplay:
    image: iago010/gameplay
    restart: always
    build: .
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
      SPRING.DATASOURCE.URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3308/gameplay?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
      SPRING.DATASOURCE.USERNAME: root
      SPRING.DATASOURCE.PASSWORD: ***
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: mvn spring-boot:run
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - erudio-network
networks:
  erudio-network:
    driver: bridge

dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

application.yml:
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gameplay
    username: root
    password: admin
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    show-sql: false
server:
  port: 90
security:
  jwt:
    token:
      secret-key: 53cr37
spring-doc:
  paths-to-match:
    - /**
  swagger-ui:
    use-root-path: true

I hope that when the command "docker compose up -d --build" is run, it will load the application container and run normally

Please always add the full stack trace of the error. Also the one line you added does not look like it has anything to do with mysql or docker (from that one line one)...

@JorgeCampos logs: https://pastecord.com/ixusejafup

@IagoAntunes Please paste the logs here in the question. Do not link to third party sites.

SPRING.DATASOURCE.URL (and its friends) should be SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL use _ instead of . for environment variables. Also please add the full stacktrace the snippet you provided provides no information.

Can you add your UserDetailsService and JwtTokenProvider classes? I can help you!
